# Django: How to override verbose_name and help_text of model fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I need some morre input/opinion on the following matter:

I want to overwrite the verbose_name and help_text for all fields of certain django models.

I already have a structure where these values are stored into the database.
Fields are iterated through:

```
Contract._meta.get_fields()
```

The I use a formset with initial/default values for this fields. This is working nicely so far. My problem now is that I want to keep the default values within the model and want to override this everywhere the values are accessed (admin-forms, form, templates etc.).

I think something like a Mixin although I thing then I would have to change too much of the django-code. Other possibility which already worked is to call a function instead of verbose_name and help_text.

For example:

```
title = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=get_vname('title') help_text=get_help_text('title'))
title_long = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=get_vname('title_long') help_text=get_help_text('title_long'))
```

But thats too much manual changes and I need to store the defaults as well. 
Is there a better way (DRY) to achieve this? Maybe there is an extension?

Comment: So you want to override what has been set on your `model`? Where is your `model` and `form` code?

Comment: I would create a Mixin and override the `__init__` method on that. However way you end up solving it, it will require some re-factoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a mixin for this now and

```
class ChangeFieldNamesMixin(models.Model):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    model_fields = self._meta.get_fields()
    initialise_texts(self._meta.model_name, model_fields)
    super(ChangeFieldNamesMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class Meta:
    abstract = Trueenter code here

def initialise_texts(name, model_fields):
model_field_name = name + 'Field'
Model = apps.get_model("custom", model_field_name)
field_names_to_create = []
field_dict = compose_field_dict(name, Model)

# create entries in table if empty
if len(field_dict) == 0:
    for entry in model_fields:
        if entry.editable:
            attrs = {'name': entry.name, 'help_text': entry.help_text, 'label': entry.verbose_name}
            new_entry = Model(**attrs)
            field_names_to_create.append(new_entry)

            print('Saving {}'.format(new_entry))
    field_list = Model.objects.bulk_create(field_names_to_create)
    compose_field_dict(name, Model, field_list)
else:

    for entry in model_fields:
        if entry.editable:
            key = entry.name

            if key in field_dict.keys():
                setattr(entry, 'verbose_name', field_dict[key].label)
                setattr(entry, 'help_text', field_dict[key].help_text)
```

I am not too glad with that solution because I think there must be a better way to initialise the fields within the database. I am quite new to django and python development (more experienced in Java) so some input would be appreciated.